# How to change target of Asp.net mvc Project in Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: .net-4.0, target, visual-web-developer

I want to use DataContractJsonSerializ class inside my Asp.net MVC Application. To be able to use it I found out that Im supposed to target a different the .NET 4.0 Framework.

But how can I change the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project, select 'Properties'. Under the 'Application' tab from the 'Target Framework' drop down, select '.NET Framework 4'